# How to dynamically add id property in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple section in which a user can add movie details using a form. I am taking the values entered by the user and creating an object from them which I pushing in to an array. However I also want to include a dynamic ID for each added movie.

```js
$("#btnAddMovie").click(function(e) {
  console.log('btn-movie triggered');

  var jsonData = [];
  var formData = $("#movieForm").serializeArray();

  $.each(formData, function() {
    console.log(formData);
    jsonData.push({
      title: formData[0].value,
      movieurl: formData[1].value,
      movieid: '1'
    });
  });

  console.log(jsonData);

  var params = JSON.stringify({
    movies: jsonData
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      params: params
    },
    url: 'save_to_json.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      $('#msg').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#error-msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      $('#error-msg').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

The above solution gives me this

```js
{
  "movies": [{
    "title": "fdfdfd",
    "movieurl": "http:\/\/meed.audiencevideo.com\/videos",
    "movieid": "1"
  }, {
    "title": "fdfdfd",
    "movieurl": "http:\/\/meed.audiencevideo.com\/videos",
    "movieid": "1"
  }]
}
```

I want `movieid` to increment dynamically eg `movieid: 1`, `movieid: 2` etc. What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: Where exactly should the `movieId` value come from? If you want them to be incremental then the property seems completely redundant, as the value will just be the object's index in the array +1

Comment: You want this increment for each element in the array?

Comment: Creating unique ids should be done where the data is consolidated - on the  server. What happens when you have 30 users all adding movies at the client and the data is then aggregated on the server - can you guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: hii guys I just want a unique Id, always should be different with the rest

Comment: @user9964622 - Always should be different with the rest **on the SERVER**?

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you can use the index in the callback in the `$.each`

```
....
$.each(formData, function(index) {
   console.log(formData);
   jsonData.push({
      title: formData[0].value,
      movieurl: formData[1].value,
      movieid: index + 1
    });
  });
...
```

To understand the callback, see the jquery documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

---

Alternatively you can also use the `jsonData.length`

```
....
$.each(formData, function(index) {
   console.log(formData);
   jsonData.push({
      title: formData[0].value,
      movieurl: formData[1].value,
      movieid: jsonData.length + 1
    });
  });
...
```

Comment: On every new run of the is code, the ids will be duplicated since they will always start with an array length of zero. Note - the OP is pushing this array to a server.

Comment: You are still deriving the ID on the client without regard to what is already on the server. this won't work either.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Updated the ans, my previous solution would work too. I'm using `jsonData.length` which would update each time as objects are pushed into it.

Comment: Question doesn't say anything about the server.

Comment: That is done on the client without regard to what is on the server. You're missing the point. While the question doesn't, the OP is pushing the data to the server - where they will no longer be unique and will likely end up over writing the previous id'd records.

Comment: While the question doesn't say anything of that sort. If you need that, you can use a hash function which would generate a unique ID based on the movie name. Or get the existing IDs from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a parameter in the callback function. The parameters are (index, array), but you would only need index.

```
  $.each(formData, function(i) {
    console.log(formData);
    jsonData.push({
      title: formData[0].value,
      movieurl: formData[1].value,
      movieid: i + 1
    });
  });
```

Comment: This won't work for the same reason the other answers won't work. You are deriving the Id on the client without regard to what is already on the server. Ids will duplicate every time this JS is run (each new page load).

Comment: I know, but what other way is there? Can there be an other way?

Comment: Two ways: 1) make a call to the server to get the next id to be used (not recommended), or 2) have the server apply the ID. #2 has been in practice for >20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solution provided by friends here are not well constructed, they don't give a perfect solution to my problem.

Most of the common problems were pointed out by @Randy Casburn

Here is my solution I found out working perfectly, I thought it will be good to share, maybe will help someone out there.

my json file looks like this

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "title": "sdsds",
            "movieurl": "https:\/\/meed.audiencevideo.com\/videos\/good_job.mp4",
            "movieid": 1,
            "buttons": []
        },
        {
            "title": "sdsds",
            "movieurl": "https:\/\/meed.audiencevideo.com\/videos\/do_you_want.mp4",
            "movieid": 2,
            "buttons": []
        },
  ]
}
```

Here is my js

```
function getNextMovieId() {
        var nextmovieid = 0;
        for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                if( movies[a].movieid>nextmovieid ) {
                        nextmovieid = movies[a].movieid;
                }
        }
        nextmovieid++;
        return nextmovieid;
}

  $("#btnAddMovie").click(function(e){

   var formData = $("#movieForm").serializeArray();
                             console.log(formData);
                             movies.push({
                                title: formData[0].value,
                                movieurl: formData[1].value,
                                movieid:  getNextMovieId(),
                                buttons: []
                            });

})
```